# Select a varaible range to delete the data . the range may vary every time the macro runs

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

```
   Range("A1").Select
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select

   Dim Q As String
   
   Q = ActiveCell.Address
   
   Range(" Q:D10438").Select
   Selection.ClearContents
```

The Variable Q is taking the value of the active cell, but i am unable to include it in range

Comment: If you're trying to find the last row in column A, [see this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Answer (score 0):

The variable cannot be included in the quotes.  Also you should avoid using `Select`.  A simpler version would be:

```
   Dim Q As String
   Q = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3).Address
   Range(Q & ":D10438").ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

### Range Object

- [How to avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
- When defining a range from two cells, the  [`Range object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) 'allows' us to use cell range objects or cell range addresses or a mix of them:

  ```
  Dim rng as range
  Set rng = Range("A1","D4")
  Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("D4"))
  ' Mix
  Set rng = Range("A1", Range("D4"))
  Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), "D4")
  ```

  to get the range:

  ```
  $A$1:$D$4
  ```
- We can apply the second 'mix solution' to the question:

  ```
  ' First cell range
  Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3)
  ' Second cell address
  "D10438"
  ```

  to get the result:

  ```
  Range(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3), "D10438").ClearContents
  ```